# Creating plugin using simple_html_dom parser?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, include

I'm running into a problem with my plugin which is essentially an admin page that includes simple_html_dom parser to edit some information scraped from some websites.

Let's assume I want to parse this page: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

And store all question Titles as $item[0] and question's URLs as $item[1].

My plugin folder is called test and has a structure as follows:

```
admin.php
index.php
scrape.php
simple_html_dom.php
```

index.php looks like this:

```
function test_admin() {  
    include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/admin.php' );  
}
```

Which imports admin.php which looks like this:

```
<?php include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'scrape.php'); ?>
```

Which imports scrape.php which looks like this:

```
<?php
# don't forget the library
include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'simple_html_dom.php');

# this is the global array we fill with article information
$articles = array();

# passing in the first page to parse, it will crawl to the end
# on its own
getArticles('https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/');

function getArticles($page) {
global $urls, $articles, $descriptions;

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($page);

$items = $html->find('div[class=summary]');

foreach($items as $post) {
    # remember comments count as nodes

    $articles[] = array($post->children(0)->plaintext, // Title
                        $post->find('a',0)->href); // URL
}

// print_r($articles);   <--- WORKS, contains full contents of parsed page!

# lets see if there's a next page
if($next = $html->find('a[class=nextpostslink]', 0)) {
    $URL = $next->href;
    echo "going on to $URL <<<\n";
    # memory leak clean up
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    getArticles($URL);
}

$html->clear();
print_r($articles) <--- WORKS, array is full of parsed info!
}
print_r($articles) <--- DOESN'T WORK, array is magically empty!
?>

<?php 
foreach($articles as $item) {
echo '<a href="'.$item[1].'">$item[0]</a>';
echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

My problem is that while the plugin does appear to include the parser's php file (evidenced by print_r($articles) containing the parsed page!), it doesn't seem to be able to loop through the array.

So, here is the output of my array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => +100 [1] => /questions/81544/using-plural-only-translation-of-register-post-status-in-plugin ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Check if page/post has any anchors that link to an image jpg/gif/png [1] => /questions/53585/check-if-page-post-has-any-anchors-that-link-to-an-image-jpg-gif-png ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Can this be done? Create 50x50 thumbnails of all existing featured images? [1] => /questions/82246/can-this-be-done-create-50x50-thumbnails-of-all-existing-featured-images ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Creating plugin using simple_html_dom parser? [1] => /questions/82096/creating-plugin-using-simple-html-dom-parser ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Warning/Error in Admin Panel while developing theme [1] => /questions/82245/warning-error-in-admin-panel-while-developing-theme ) [5] => Array ( [0] => Chose gallery display type [1] => /questions/82244/chose-gallery-display-type ) [6] => Array ( [0] => Why the JavaScript code is ignored from wp editor? [1] => /questions/33539/why-the-javascript-code-is-ignored-from-wp-editor ) [7] => Array ( [0] => How to list only child categories? [1] => /questions/82178/how-to-list-only-child-categories ) [8] => Array ( [0] => How to get the post_status in javascript on post admin page? [1] => /questions/82226/how-to-get-the-post-status-in-javascript-on-post-admin-page ) [9] => Array ( [0] => WP_Query orderby breaks when using AJAX? [1] => /questions/82092/wp-query-orderby-breaks-when-using-ajax ) [10] => Array ( [0] => Wordpress on Ubuntu 12.10: permalinks problem [1] => /questions/82225/wordpress-on-ubuntu-12-10-permalinks-problem ) [11] => Array ( [0] => Filtering taxonomies to a single post [1] => /questions/82240/filtering-taxonomies-to-a-single-post ) [12] => Array ( [0] => Display Parent Category of a Post belonging only to Subcategory [1] => /questions/58496/display-parent-category-of-a-post-belonging-only-to-subcategory ) [13] => Array ( [0] => Make display name unique [1] => /questions/82239/make-display-name-unique ) [14] => Array ( [0] => Send AJAX response from a non jQuery function [1] => /questions/82238/send-ajax-response-from-a-non-jquery-function ) [15] => Array ( [0] => Sorting by 2 Custom Fields + Post Title [1] => /questions/32175/sorting-by-2-custom-fields-post-title ) [16] => Array ( [0] => How to show one page with two different templates [1] => /questions/82223/how-to-show-one-page-with-two-different-templates ) [17] => Array ( [0] => flat category urls but retain heirchy? [1] => /questions/82236/flat-category-urls-but-retain-heirchy ) [18] => Array ( [0] => How do I get rid of “category” from my URL structure? [1] => /questions/30128/how-do-i-get-rid-of-category-from-my-url-structure ) [19] => Array ( [0] => Are the wordpress Core css styles really all nessasary? [1] => /questions/82228/are-the-wordpress-core-css-styles-really-all-nessasary ) [20] => Array ( [0] => Cannot access dashboard after upgrading to 3.5 [1] => /questions/76447/cannot-access-dashboard-after-upgrading-to-3-5 ) [21] => Array ( [0] => $wpdb error (Call to a member function insert() on a non-object) [1] => /questions/82229/wpdb-error-call-to-a-member-function-insert-on-a-non-object ) [22] => Array ( [0] => Registering tags taxonomy for a custom post type [1] => /questions/82217/registering-tags-taxonomy-for-a-custom-post-type ) [23] => Array ( [0] => register_post_type name character limit [1] => /questions/82227/register-post-type-name-character-limit ) [24] => Array ( [0] => IP location based country language of wordpress site [1] => /questions/78023/ip-location-based-country-language-of-wordpress-site ) [25] => Array ( [0] => Include Post Format in permalink [1] => /questions/70627/include-post-format-in-permalink ) [26] => Array ( [0] => How to detect first visit of a user? [1] => /questions/82211/how-to-detect-first-visit-of-a-user ) [27] => Array ( [0] => Repositioning 'Reply' Link in Comments [1] => /questions/82218/repositioning-reply-link-in-comments ) [28] => Array ( [0] => How do I approach removing menu items on the fly based on settings in my plugin? [1] => /questions/82180/how-do-i-approach-removing-menu-items-on-the-fly-based-on-settings-in-my-plugin ) [29] => Array ( [0] => Custom meta boxes text field unique id [1] => /questions/82222/custom-meta-boxes-text-field-unique-id ) [30] => Array ( [0] => Using Disqus, how to stop storing comments in wp database? [1] => /questions/58417/using-disqus-how-to-stop-storing-comments-in-wp-database ) [31] => Array ( [0] => How can I Add a variable PHP in the Menu Nav [1] => /questions/82194/how-can-i-add-a-variable-php-in-the-menu-nav ) [32] => Array ( [0] => Having a lot of difficulty getting add_editor_style() to load into source code [1] => /questions/60092/having-a-lot-of-difficulty-getting-add-editor-style-to-load-into-source-code ) [33] => Array ( [0] => How to custom change author base without $this->front? [1] => /questions/82004/how-to-custom-change-author-base-without-this-front ) [34] => Array ( [0] => Rename image uploads with width in filename [1] => /questions/82193/rename-image-uploads-with-width-in-filename ) [35] => Array ( [0] => Get a post's ID [1] => /questions/82208/get-a-posts-id ) [36] => Array ( [0] => Apply custom names for generic custom taxonomy name? [1] => /questions/82184/apply-custom-names-for-generic-custom-taxonomy-name ) [37] => Array ( [0] => Get post meta in enqueued js file [1] => /questions/82209/get-post-meta-in-enqueued-js-file ) [38] => Array ( [0] => How do I only load a plugin js on it's settings pages? [1] => /questions/82032/how-do-i-only-load-a-plugin-js-on-its-settings-pages ) [39] => Array ( [0] => remove post and categories/tags count from right now dashboard widget [1] => /questions/82132/remove-post-and-categories-tags-count-from-right-now-dashboard-widget ) [40] => Array ( [0] => Styling Contact Form 7 fields [1] => /questions/82207/styling-contact-form-7-fields ) [41] => Array ( [0] => Woocommerce: Changing catalog image sizes [1] => /questions/82197/woocommerce-changing-catalog-image-sizes ) [42] => Array ( [0] => Tracing the life of a query [1] => /questions/82183/tracing-the-life-of-a-query ) [43] => Array ( [0] => Custom WP_Query with complex 'post_status' argument [1] => /questions/82200/custom-wp-query-with-complex-post-status-argument ) [44] => Array ( [0] => Get a single post by a unique meta value [1] => /questions/82203/get-a-single-post-by-a-unique-meta-value ) [45] => Array ( [0] => 2 item in a same menu pointing to 1 page [1] => /questions/46962/2-item-in-a-same-menu-pointing-to-1-page ) [46] => Array ( [0] => Modify Notification Message When Profile Updated [1] => /questions/37358/modify-notification-message-when-profile-updated ) [47] => Array ( [0] => Change wordpress meta tag description using WP functions [1] => /questions/82196/change-wordpress-meta-tag-description-using-wp-functions ) )
```

In short:
- simple_html_dom is in fact being included (tested with breakpoints)
- $articles array does contain the parsed page (evidence above) BUT
- $articles seems to empty itself when called from outside the getArticles() function.

Is anyone willing to help find out why I am having this problem?

Comment: One place to start would be to throw some breakpoints in `simple_html_dom.php` and trace the problem.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: There are probably more elegant solutions, but I use `die("i'm dead!");` and place it somewhere in the code. If it dies, move it further down the execution. Repeat as necessary. Especially handy in conditionals to see whether something branches as expected.

Comment: @Jonathan could you upload your code ? You said "plus other code that functions fine" and "has other code that functions fine" but maybe its not working fine :)

Comment: @AKTed found the root cause of the problem. the parser does work. The problem is $articles array is emptying itself when called from outside the getArticles function. Question is, why?

Comment: @Klian See my updates. Problem isn't the extra code, I removed it all in my testing in trying to find the problem. I'm playing with EXACTLY what is posted here, no extra code is left.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but in your first `print_r($articles)`, the global variable `$articles` is in scope of the `getArticles()` function, so we're all good there. But, in your second `print_r($articles)` which is happening after the closing brace of the `getArticles()` function declaration, `$articles` has not been globalized, and is therefore, just set to the empty array. Doing a `global $articles` prior to your second `print_r($articles)` should work.

Comment: You're correct! My how a simple oversight can ruin everything! Thank you.

Comment: Cool! Added and an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but in your first `print_r($articles)`, the global variable `$articles` is in the scope of the `getArticles()` function, so we're all good there. But, in your second `print_r($articles)`, which is happening after the closing brace of the `getArticles()` function declaration, `$articles` has not been globalized. So, it's just set to the empty array.

Doing a `global $articles` prior to your second `print_r($articles)` should give you the results.